# First row not animating while deletion iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to delete row by using following code

```
[myTable beginUpdates];
[myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[myTable endUpdates];
```

Animation is working fine for all rows except for first row,

Please let me know reasons/solution if any

Thanks

Comment: first all the time? first when it's the only row in the section? doesn't work how - what does it do instead?

Comment: @Wain, yes it happens only if single row is there, it doesn't show animation

Answer (score 0):

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // animation has finished
      NSLog(@"My Animation Ended "); //Check if this is printed when zero index is deleted.
}];

[myTable beginUpdates];
            [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[myTable endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

If it is printed, means there was animation, so we could conclude why its not showing.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 1 row in the section then you shouldn't be deleting that row, you should be deleting the section.

Note that in all cases you also need to update the data store to remove the row / section at the same time that you update the table view with the change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved,

The problem was i was setting alpha of table to zero immediately after calling delete animation as shown below, anyway thanks for your replies.

---

```
[myTable beginUpdates];

[myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

[myTable endUpdates];

myTable.alpha = 0;
```